# How to automatically insert a space after every comma in a textbox using JQuery?

Tags: jquery, user-input

I trying to write a script using jQuery, it is suppose to automatically put a space after every comma "," in order to separate a sequence of numbers that user input in an input field. e.g. if they enter (45,68,95,23) it becomes (45, 68, 95, 23) when the user moves away from the input field.

Got this to check if the input has a comma or not

```
$("#test").blur(function() { 
    if(this.value.indexOf(",") !== -1) {
        alert('got a comma');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply split the input value by commas, trim the spaces off each item, then join the resulting array back together with a comma and space.

```
$("#test").blur(function () {
  this.value = $.map(this.value.split(","), $.trim).join(", ");
});
```

Comment: +1 just for the rarely-seen joy of passing in a library function as a lambda.

Comment: @Phrogz , what does that mean?

Comment: @qwertymk The second parameter to `$.map(...)` needs to be a function. Usually you would see something like: `$.map( ..., function(s){ return ... } );` but Todd here has re-used an existing jQuery function and passed it by providing its reference without the following parentheses that would cause it to be immediately invoked.

Answer (score 7):

```
$('#test').blur(function(){
  $(this).val(function(i,oldValue){
    return oldValue.replace( /,\s*/g, ', ' );
  });
});
```

Or, with less jQuery:

```
$('#test').blur(function(){
  this.value = this.value.replace( /,\s*/g, ', ' );
});
```

Comment: With even less `jQuery`: `document.getElementById('test').onblur = function() { this.value = this.value.replace(/,\s*/g, ', '); };`

Comment: Uh... the first method is totally unnecessary, since the second is superior in every way.

Comment: @JacobRelkin Heh :) Of course this suffers from the improbable problem of needing to attach multiple blur handlers to the element, but always good to keep the populace aware of non-jQuery options. +1 for humor and inclusion of all appropriate semicolons.

Comment: @YiJiang I agree that the latter is superior. I included the former to push awareness of the benefits of using the function-form of `val()` (no repeated jQuery object, no re-querying for the old value).

Comment: Unless the only thing your JavaScript is going to do is insert a comma, no other DOM manipulations, no animations or event handlers on items identified by class or other attributes, then it's a little silly to fight against using JQuery and insist on raw JavaScript only.  I see so many developers waste so much precious time because they feel it's cheating to use a tried and tested framework to meet their business goals, all for just a few milliseconds in page load time.  Of course, for academic purposes, it's always good to try to learn some basics so you know what goes on under the hood. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
this.value=this.value.replace(/,/gim,', ');
```

Comment: @Anonymous `String.prototype.replace` is non-mutating in JavaScript.

Comment: I don't even know what that means. Couldn't you just use the String() function if type is an issue?

Comment: @Anonymous I mean that calling the `replace` on the `value` will not change the value; it will only return a new string. You would need `this.value = this.value.replace...`. There's also no reason for either the `i` or `m` modifiers on your regex.

Comment: You're right, I overlooked that. However, I think //gim is good practice. This user has obviously never heard of regex.

Answer (score 0):

Using regex, this will normalize the whitespace around each comma to one U+0020 space character after, happening when the text box loses focus after changing value. It also trims whitespace (or a stray comma) from the beginning and end:

```
$("#test").change(function() {
    this.value = this.value.replace(/\s*,\s*/g, ', ').replace(/^,?\s*|,?\s*$/g, '');
});
```

Regex is also helpful for telling the user whether his input is valid or not. [Try this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rfQbJ/5/):

```
$("#test").focus(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('valid invalid');
}).blur(function() {
    this.value = this.value.replace(/\s*,\s*/g, ', ').replace(/^,?\s*|,?\s*$/g, '');
    if(/^(?:[\d.](?:, )?)*$/.test(this.value)) {
        $(this).addClass('valid');
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('invalid');
    }
});
```