# Automatically inserting a space after every comma using JQuery?

Tags: jquery

I'm not sure what I'm doing that's causing this to not fire in Wordpress:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$("#space-comma").blur(function () {
this.value = $.map(this.value.split(","), $.trim).join(", ");
});
});
</script>
```

I pretty much lifted this code verbatim as it matched my use case pretty much spot on.. [How to automatically insert a space after every comma in a textbox using JQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4703880/how-to-automatically-insert-a-space-after-every-comma-in-a-textbox-using-jquery)
The only difference is that I'm trying to inject the space in between two or more values being pulled from a DB field rather than formatting a textbox.

Thanks!

Comment: What problem are you having? If you understand what this code is doing, it should be obviousl how to use the same method on the values from the DB.

Comment: A simpler way to do this is with `value = value.replace(/,/g, ", ")`

Comment: If you want this to be done with values from a DB, putting it in code that processes the value of a text box won't work. Unless you first put the value from the DB into the text box. But this code only runs after the user edits the textbox. You shouldn't use an event handler if you want it done some other time.

Comment: Remove the `blur` line, change `this` to the input you want to change:  `$("#space-comma").val($.map($("#space-comma)").val().split(","), $.trim).join(" , "))` to use your code, but obv .replaceAll / replace(/,/g would be better.

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
function modifyTextContent(element) {
    var group = jQuery(element).text();
    var newText = group.replace(/,/g, ', ');
    jQuery(element).text(newText);
}
```

Comment: On its own, this won't do anything.  You're defining a new function, so it doesn't *need* to be in doc.ready, but then you're not calling that function, and you're missing `})` - so I guess you're also missing some other code.